# UITableView was deallocated IOS SWIFT Random Crash

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, observers

I am just loading the view from custom cell in Storyboard. But after two or three times the following error occurs

```
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'An instance 0x7ba90000 of class UITableView was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it. Current observation info: <NSKeyValueObservationInfo 0x7c66ee20> (
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x7c66edf0: Observer: 0x7c68bce0, Key path: contentSize, Options: <New: NO, Old: NO, Prior: NO> Context: 0x0, Property: 0x7b633050>
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x7c68e1c0: Observer: 0x7c68bce0, Key path: contentOffset, Options: <New: NO, Old: NO, Prior: NO> Context: 0x0, Property: 0x7b609030>
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x7c68e8a0: Observer: 0x7c68bce0, Key path: frame, Options: <New: NO, Old: NO, Prior: NO> Context: 0x0, Property: 0x7b60c300>
```

Following is my written code. Please have a look and let me know where I am going wrong.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            // let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

            var identifier = "cell"

            if indexPath.row == tblData.count{

                identifier = "cell1"

            }
            var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier) as UITableViewCell!
            if (cell == nil) {
                cell = UITableViewCell(style:.Default, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
            }
            cell.selectionStyle = .None

            if identifier == "cell1"{

                let cellBtnDownload =  cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIButton
                cellBtnDownload.addTarget(self, action: #selector(PlayListDetailController.btnDownload(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
                return cell

            }

            let cellLbl =  cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
            let cellBtn =  cell.viewWithTag(2) as! UIButton
            cellLbl.text = tblData.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("t_name") as? String
            print(String(indexPath.row))
            cellBtn.accessibilityValue = String(indexPath.row)
            cellBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(PlayListDetailController.BtnPlaySong(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)



            return cell
        }
```

have a look
thanks

Comment: Seems like cellForRowAtIndex you are still writing like objective c. do you have custom cell in nib or storyboard itself with table view ?

Comment: i have checked. Its showing crash in my simulator but working fine in device. behaving starnge

Comment: Your code is odd. Firstly, you are dequeueing a generic tableview cell. Secondly, you are using the older `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` and not the newer `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` which guarantees a non-nil tableview cell. Thirdly, you also appear to be adding multiple buttons to each `cell1` without removing them which will cause errors eventually. Fourthly, using `viewWithTag` can break very easily - a better technique would be creating a custom subclass and using outlets on custom cell. This will also mean you do not have to add buttons and targets at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing any custom observers for contentSize or contentOffset or frame. If you are adding any to your UITableView or your UITableViewCell